# Script to extract header with data from oracle query & export into csv file

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am using one query as below. I want to export result set of below query into csv file.

```
select a.eid, b.ename, c.pid, b.pnm 
from tab1 a join tab2 b on a.eid=b.eid
join tab3 c on b.pid=c.pid;
```

I want to extract csv file from the above result set along with headers & save into `C:\User\mows\` folder using Stored procedure or any script. So I need result set with header in csv like below format. Could you please help me on this.

```
EID     ENAME     PID    PNM
---     -----     ---    ---
1001    Steve     21     IT
1003    Tim       23     Management
1005    Craig     25     Account
.......................
```

Data along with headers in csv file when above `SQL` query run.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your tables; the `INSERT` statement for some sample data; the expected output for that sample data; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; details of the application you are using to connect to the database (do you want a pure PL/SQL solution or an SQL/Plus script to `SPOOL` the output or a SQL Developer solution or something else?)

Comment: @MT0 Thanks for reply but I used `spool` which is not working here each table having many columns but i have to select just few columns in above `SQL` query.

Comment: What tool are you using ? With sqldeveloper and sqlcl export to csv is a breeze.

Comment: @KoenLostrie `Toad` I am using

Comment: Might be worth installing sqlcl for this purpose only - it will make your life easier, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using SQLcl - this is the command line client using the same engine as sqldeveloper. This allows passing hints in the sql query to format the output. For csv, this is a solution:

```
scott>select /*csv*/ * from emp;

"EMPNO","ENAME","JOB","MGR","HIREDATE","SAL","COMM","DEPTNO"
7839,"KING","PRESIDENT",,17/11/81,5001,,10
7698,"BLAKE","MANAGER",7839,01/05/81,2850,,30
7782,"CLARK","MANAGER",7839,09/06/81,2450,,10
7566,"JONES","MANAGER",7839,02/04/81,2975,,20
7788,"SCOTT","ANALYST",7566,09/12/82,3000,,20
7902,"FORD","ANALYST",7566,03/12/81,3000,,20
7369,"SMITH","CLERK",7902,17/12/80,801,,20
7499,"ALLEN","SALESMAN",7698,20/02/81,1600,300,30
7521,"WARD","SALESMAN",7698,22/02/81,1250,500,30
7654,"MARTIN","SALESMAN",7698,28/09/81,1250,1400,30
7844,"TURNER","SALESMAN",7698,08/09/81,1500,0,30
7876,"ADAMS","CLERK",7788,12/01/83,1100,,20
7900,"JAMES","CLERK",7698,03/12/81,950,,30
7934,"MILLER","CLERK",7782,23/01/82,1300,,10

14 rows selected.
```

To spool to a file, use the `spool` command, just like in sqlplus. Example for some selected columns spooled to a file:

```
scott>spool empcsv.csv
scott>select /*csv*/ empno, ename FROM emp FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;

"EMPNO","ENAME"
7839,"KING"
7698,"BLAKE"
7782,"CLARK"
7566,"JONES"
7788,"SCOTT"

scott>spool off
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not able to see csv file where it saved in my local directory.

Comment: This was just an example of a query generating csv output. To spool to a file, user the ```spool``` command. Updated my answer.

Comment: In `TOAD` it is not working. I am not using in SQL command prompt. I am using SQL editor. So could you please let me know how to do it?

Comment: This solution is specific to sqlcl, a free tool offered by Oracle. In sqldeveloper you can also export as csv but there it is manual. I'm not familiar with Toad.